# syntax error: unexpected token " "

Tags: css, error-handling

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header
{
    background-image: url('../images/cream-gravel-texture.png');
    height: 626px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#midHeader
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url('../images/light-grey-bit-behind-logo.png');
    height: 194px;
}
#logo
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 287px;
}
#headContact
{
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 21.95px;
    color: #4b1e19;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 421px;
}
#contactUsNow
{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#navMenu ul 
{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#navMenu ul li 
{
    display:inline;
}
#navMenu ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 5px 43px 10px 0;
    font-size: 20.4px;
    padding: 5px 10px 4px 10px;
    color: #4b1e19;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;*/
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#navMenu ul li a:hover, #navMenu ul li.active a 
{
    /*line-height: 33px;*/
    background-image: url('../images/nav-hover.png');
    /*height: 33px;*/
}​
#headShadow
{
    background-image: url('../images/gradient-under-beige-bit.png');
    height: 22px;
}
```

This CSS is giving me the error in the title. What is wrong?

Comment: What are you using to report CSS errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a hidden, non-printable character right before `#headShadow`, which shows when I copy your CSS into a text editor.  Backspace over the closing `}` in the previous directive to get rid of it.

```
#navMenu ul li a:hover, #navMenu ul li.active a 
{
    /*line-height: 33px;*/
    background-image: url('../images/nav-hover.png');
    /*height: 33px;*/
}​<200b>
#headShadow
```

Comment: @RyanMurphy I couldn't say.  Probably got picked up in a copy/paste somewhere.

Comment: Ahh yeh, thats true. Thanks so much. Great help

Comment: @RyanMurphy it would be very nice to accept the answer, if it is correct

Answer (score 2):

In my case I ran the Grunt build script incorrectly.  A CSS file was compressed as Javascript and the built HTML swapped `<link rel="stylesheet">` for a `<script>` tag.  The first selector throws a JS error in the console.

In the markup `<!-- build:js ...` should have been `<!-- build:css ...`

Answer (score 1):

When I copied and pasted this in my local, I saw an unreadable character â€‹ in Firebug, before the line #headShadow and after }

Please remove delete and retype the line